# Extract specific texts from a docx throught a search query in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, fast-search

Is it possible to get only "title1" texts from a docx file stored in a library through a search query?

Also in a library of docx files, is there an automated way to crawl all "titles1" lines of a docx and display them as a "table of content like" text on the presentation page of the document library?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `SectionNames` mananaged property, unfortunately it's not searchable.

This leaves you to create a content enrichment web service and extract the titles yourself and put them in a custom managed property.